# Is ASP.NET MVC stateless?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have heard that MVC .NET is stateless. What are the implications of this and why is it that MVC is stateless.

Comment: Perhaps what was meant was that it does not keep viewstate, like ASP.NET web pages. That is true.  That choice better fits with the stateless nature of HTTP and is likely why it was chosen.  Only the designers can say with any surety, although I, for one, rejoice in the fact.

Comment: Can you please provide more info or links? As it stands right now, your question is based on an unknown statement of a doubtful "fact".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MVC is stateless because HTTP is. There is nothing in HTTP that indicates when a session starts or ends.

Every web framework tries to overcome this by using either a cookie or Request/Response features like the query string or FORM post.

Comment: You mean everything over HTTP is stateless? WebForms runs on HTTP too.

Comment: @Henk WebForms uses viewstate and POSTs to maintain state.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Yes. HTTP is stateless. There is no "session". WebForms mimics a session by using a timeout and transporting its information over the request/response structure. You will never get notified in HTTP when a user closes it's web browser / "session".

Comment: I agree that HTTP is stateless. But I don't think either MVC or WebForms is. They're just gradually different.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: They are stateless in the sense that you can never know when the user stops using your site or that the session is lost if the browser fails to transport your state parameters. Compare with FTP or IRC. They have built in session support. Try maintaining state without cookies. It's possible but ugly (the user can just remove any query string parameter or the viewstate from the POST). It's still valid HTTP, but the session will be lost.

Comment: @jgauffin Your answer is little bit off. MVC is not stateless! It is, in this particular case, built on top of a stateless technology, but if it is itslef stateless or not depends on the implementation of the MVC pattern. Remembering that MVC is not synonymous to HTTP web applications. Is a pattern and can be used in different contexts. Also, if the state is simulated or not is not interesting to the discussion, once that Classes, Strings and several other components don't really exist and are merely simulated on the processor by our programming.

Comment: @7hi4g0: The question contains the ASP.NET-MVC tag, hence it's specific to ASP.NET MVC and not to the design pattern MVC. So do the actual question title and the question itself. It would be a non-answer to give an answer about the pattern. But hey, if you think that makes this a -1 answer, then by all means, go ahead.

Comment: @jgauffin Well, that's not exactly the reason I thought it was bad answer. Reading now, my comment seems to focus too much on the MVC pattern. Sorry! Actually I downvoted because of the first sentence of the answer. The fact that HTTP is stateless doesn't make everything on top of it automatically stateless. Also, AFAIK there are mechanisms to save state in ASP.NET MVC. So it all comes down to how you use the framework. Only downvoted cause it seems to me that the __first sentence__ is __unintended__ misinformation. No hard feelings :D

Comment: MVC can never be fully stateful. If someone removes the cookie or modified the querystring the state is lost. As a developer you MUST be fully aware of this to write a fully working ASP.NET MVC application. If you educate your users and tell them that ASP.NET MVC is stateful you are just fooling them.

Comment: Also, compare WebForms with MVC. Microsoft created WebForms to get a stateful layer on top of HTTP. How well did that go? If you do a post or similar in MVC to the same page, do you get the exact same view back? No. You have to make sure that all parameters are POSTed. That's why it's stateless.

Comment: Sessions, Cookies, Querystrings, these are all things that you can use in MVC to emulate a stateful application. But that's all that it is. An emulation. Because if you forget to provide those you have no clue what so ever about the  user or the state that the user had.

Answer (score 8):

State is managed in ASP.NET (MVC and WebForms) through [several means](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx):

- Session
- Cookies
- Form posts
- Application
- Query string
- Cache
- Context

MVC eliminates ViewState, which means that controls (text boxes, checkboxes, etc.) lose their values each time a page is posted back.  You need to repopulate them manually or through other means (Model binding, for instance).

MVC isn't truly stateless, but it does remove one of the most common ways of persisting state in ASP.NET -- the ViewState.

Answer (score 5):

MVC is not (totally) stateless. No web framework is.

I think this refers to the fact that MVC abolishes the _VIEWSTATE field.

But do provide a link or more information.

Answer (score 5):

the web is stateless, therefore anything built on top of http is stateless. by stateless I mean each request/response is an atomic unit with no knowledge of any previous request.

there are mechanisms with http that allow you to hold some form of state between requests like Session and Application, but generally, these should be used as little as possible.

Webforms attempts to create the illusion of state by introducing ViewState and Postback. But this doesn't change the fact that the web is stateless.

Answer (score 2):

I would say all web communication is stateless except some of the new technologies like [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR)
`[Async signaling library for ASP.NET to help build real-time, multi-user interactive web applications]`
.

You make a request and get a response, that is it, perhaps what you are thinking of is not using ViewState like in webforms.