# MVC - Inherited view model members

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inheritance, model-binding

Requirement is to pass user inputs from view to controller and the type of view model property is to be decided on runtime. Here is my code:

**Model Structure**

```
public class MyModel
    {
        public Device Device { get; set; }
    }

    public class Device
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Vender { get; set; }
    }

    public class Mobile : Device
    {
        public string SimsSlots { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public class MyController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Test/

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult AddDevice()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SaveDevice(MyModel model)
        {
            //Save the Device
            return Content("Saved");
        }

    }
```

**View**

```
@model mvcFirst.Models.MyModel

<form action="/My/SaveDevice" method="post">
    <table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Device.Name)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Vender
            </th>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Device.Vender)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Number of sim slots
            </th>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>(m.Device as mvcFirst.Models.Mobile).SimsSlots)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I didn't found any way to make my application capable to determine that the input being saved is a mobile device.

It always shows the type as device while I need the type mobile here!
Gives this:
[image]

Comment: Very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33694972/editorfor-inheritance-model-mvc/33695817#33695817

Comment: Long and short, MVC can only bind to `Device` because that's what's in your view model. It doesn't matter if you posted `Mobile` because the instance is not preserved. The posted data is just sent as a set of string key-value pairs, and the modelbinder builds this back into a class instance based on the parameter of the action.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Any solution to this problem? Is there no way to use inherited type in view model using its base class?

Comment: No. Not when you're posting to an action. The modelbinder will only bind the values from the post body that it can line up with the classes it has to work with. It has no knowledge that `Device` has subclasses, what those subclasses are, or which of those it should choose to use instead.